# Hbase cluster running Phoenix is slow using jdbc and python phoenixdb

Tags: performance, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix, database-tuning

I have a cluster setup running HBase and a phoenix queryserver. Currently my cluster contains a master node and 3 slaves. The table I am connecting to consists of 124 columns and a total of 16 million rows. A simple `COUNT(*)` or `DISTINCT "value"` query takes around 1-2 minutes, which as far as I understood shouldn't be the case - [How fast is Phoenix? Why is it so fast?](https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html#I_want_to_get_started_Is_there_a_Phoenix_Hello_World)

In the documentation linked above a full table scan of 100 million rows should take around 20 seconds. And since my table size is significantly smaller I don't understand why my queries take that long. What could I do to optimize my queries? I plan on reconstructing my table using column families (which I know improves performance, but I was wondering if there are other ways to get quick performance boosts, as reconstructing my current table will be a quite huge task.

I am using Phoenix 4.9 and HBase 1.2.

Comment: you might want to look at column families and indexes in Phoenix.  we added indexes and the performance was over a 100 fold improvement

Comment: @PaulBastide This sounds promising. Do you know of a way to do this without deleting the entire table and creating a new?

As I mentioned I have a total of 16 million rows that are generated by some sensors, and I would hate to lose all that data.

Comment: I'd create a new table, then upsert into the new table.  It'll be a fast move using the DBMS